# Display jsPDF in browser window

Tags: electron, jspdf, quasar-framework

I am just starting to use jsPDF and I think it may actually work (after attempting a zillion different ways to produce PDFs in my Quasar/Electron desktop application that have not worked).

Is there a way to display the PDF in the application window?

```
this.doc = new jsPDF({
  orientation: "landscape",
  unit: "in",
  format: [4, 2]
 })
this.doc.text(this.dogArray[0].dogCallName, 1, 1)
this.doc.save("test.pdf")
```

That works and I can save the PDF, but I'd also like to be able to display the generated PDF in the Electron browser window.  I can console.log out this.doc, and I can display it on the window, but it's just a bunch of string info.

Is there something like doc.view("file.pdf") that can be used? I'm looking through the jsPDF documentation but I'm not seeing what I'm looking for.

I want to be able to see the PDF like the author shows on his [Demo Website](http://raw.githack.com/MrRio/jsPDF/master/index.html)

Comment: Okay thanks. I will see what I can figure out. :)